# Is it Possible to Iterate over Multiple Dict Keys at Once?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, iteration

I have a problem I'm working on for an online MOOC I'm studying now with writing a function that takes a list of drugs and see which virus from a list of viruses is resistant to all of the drugs.

I have already solved it using a flag, but I'm trying to find other ways to solve it.
One method I thought of is, if possible, to use the drugs list all at once and as the key and get the values as a list in return, which obviously won't work (I found after searching that I can't use lists as dict keys).
So my question is this: is it possible to use an iterable as a dict key, where each element of that iterable is a separate key of the dict?

I have tried using lists with no luck, but I knew that tuples can be made as dict keys, but only if the tuple itself is a distinct key, not the elements of it.

Here is the function I thought of:

```py
def getResistPop(self, drugResist):
        """
        Get the population of virus particles resistant to the drugs listed in
        drugResist.       

        drugResist: Which drug resistances to include in the population (a list
        of strings - e.g. ['guttagonol'] or ['guttagonol', 'srinol'])

        returns: The population of viruses (an integer) with resistances to all
        drugs in the drugResist list.
        """

        totalPop = 0
        for v in self.viruses:
            if all(v.resistances[drugResist]):
                totalPop += 1
```

This is the best I could do not using a flag.
But of course it wouldn't work, giving the error that a list can't be used as a dict key.
I want to know if something similar to that is possible or not.
Thanks!

Edit: as per @Yongkang Zhao request, here is some sample data:

A test run had this info:

```
virus1 = ResistantVirus(1.0, 0.0, {"drug1": True}, 0.0)
virus2 = ResistantVirus(1.0, 0.0, {"drug1": False, "drug2": True}, 0.0)
virus3 = ResistantVirus(1.0, 0.0, {"drug1": True, "drug2": True}, 0.0)
patient = sm.TreatedPatient([virus1, virus2, virus3], 100)
patient.getResistPop(['drug1']): 2
patient.getResistPop(['drug2']): 2
patient.getResistPop(['drug1','drug2']): 1
patient.getResistPop(['drug3']): 0
patient.getResistPop(['drug1', 'drug3']): 0
patient.getResistPop(['drug1','drug2', 'drug3']): 0
```

The number after each line of calling getResistPop is the expected number of viruses resisting all the drugs administered.

Comment: can you post some sample data to work with?

Comment: post `drugResist` contents and expected result

Comment: What is the `self.viruses[virus].resistances` data structure? A dictionary?

Comment: "is it possible to use an iterable as a dict key..." - yes: `{'ab': 5}['ab']`, where `'ab'` is the iterable; "...where each element of that iterable is a separate key of the dict?" - yes: `{'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'ab': 30}['ab']`. Is this what you meant to ask? I think your question is whether it's possible to retrieve the element of the dictionary at index `k` for each `k` in some iterable, isn't it?

Comment: @YongkangZhao added some more data. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, a dictionary mapping the drug to the resistance state of that virus to the drug.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest updated the post with an example of calling the function that should satisfy your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed function is close, you're just not using `all()` correctly.

```
def getResistPop(self, drugResist):
    """<trimmed>"""

    totalPop = 0
    for v in self.viruses:
        if all(x in v.resistances for x in drugResist):
            totalPop += 1
```

To clarify - you're not really iterating multiple dict keys at once in this case, but rather checking if all your drugs are found in the virus's set of resistances, per virus.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very close to the one I'm looking for, but it gave me the insight I wanted. I had one slight modification to it and it's now working like a charm! :D Here's the one I made: ```def getResistPop(self, drugResist):     """<trimmed>"""      totalPop = 0         for v in self.viruses:             if all(d in v.resistances and v.resistances[d] for d in drugResist):                 totalPop += 1                  return totalPop```

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Mon'em good call, I forgot your dict values were bools. Glad it helped!